# Simplifying $\sum_{i=1}^n{\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \rfloor}$?

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, harmonic-numbers

In a few programming contexts, I've come across code along these lines:

```
total = 0
for i from 1 to n
    total := total + n / i
```

Where the division here is integer division. Mathematically, this boils down to evaluating

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left\lfloor\, n \over i\,\right\rfloor.$$

This is upper-bounded by $n H_{n}$ and lower-bounded by $nH_{n} - n$ using the standard inequalities for $\texttt{floor}$'s, but that upper bound likely has a large gap to the true value.

Is there a way to either get an exact value for this summation or find some simpler function it's asymptotically equivalent to?

Comment: Should "contexts" be "contests"?

Comment: Actually, no! I was wondering if anyone would ask that. :-)

Comment: The upper bound is $nH_n$ not $H_n$. (And the lower bound is correspondingly $n(H_n-1)$, which is at least good enough for asymptotics)

Comment: Oh whoops! Let me fix that.

Comment: A better lower bound is $(n+1)\,H_n-n$.  Now, the gap between the two bounds is $n-H_n$ (still $\Omega(n)$, though).

Comment: This is known as [divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function). It can be computed in $O(\sqrt{x})$ time. Look at the wiki page for refs and more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For exact computation, a simplification begins with the observation

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor 
= \sum_{i,j} [1 \leq i] [1 \leq j] [ij \leq n] 1$$

where $[P]$ is the Iverson bracket: it is $1$ if $P$ is true, and $0$ if false.

Anyways, using the symmetry, you can break this down to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor 
= -\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor^2  + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor  $$

This form is better for making rough estimates too, since the roundoff error is a much smaller proportion of the summands.

Comment: This is also known as dirichlet's hyperbola method

Comment: I write it $\sum_{i \ge 1,j \ge 1} 1_{ij \ge n}$

Answer (score 5):

See [OES sequence A006218](https://oeis.org/A006218) and [Dirichlet divisor problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletDivisorProblem.html).  Asymptotically we have 
$$a(n) = n (\log n + 2 \gamma - 1) + O(n^\theta)$$
where the optimal value of $\theta$ is an unsolved problem: the best result given on that MathWorld page is  $\theta = 131/416$, due to Huxley in 2003.

Answer (score 4):

Your sum is also equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n \tau(i)$. Notice that if we were able to calculate this sum really fast we would also be able to determine whether $n$ is prime really fast, so calculating your sum is not very easy.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\tau(i)?$

Comment: yeah, my bad.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: What is the function $\tau(i)$ here? Number of divisors of $i$?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but how would this help you tell if $n$ were prime?

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \tau(i)+2 =\sum_{i=0}^{n}\tau(i)\iff n$ is prime