# Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\lfloor n/k\rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $n$ be a natural number. Prove that 
>   $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor n/k\rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ is even.

I tried to introduce the fractional part, but it didnt help me.
Next, I considered an inequality to create a bound, but that too was in vain. Next I found out that $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor x/2 \rfloor +\lfloor x+1/2 \rfloor$.
I applied this, but as all were as a sum, it became hard for me to cancel out and it made my work difficult. Now the next problem is about the square root in the box. I once saw in an example that

$$\lfloor \sqrt{n}+ \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor = \sqrt{4n+1}$$

Now even if this may seem useful, I cannot understand how to remove the $\lfloor \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor $ from the identity. Any help would be helpful!

Comment: Please format your question through latex.

Comment: I do not know how to use latexx

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you mean $\lfloor x \rfloor$? You did mention largest integer not exceeding $x$.

Comment: Yes the floor function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor^2$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ have the same parity it suffices to show the following identity
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor n/k\rfloor=2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor} \lfloor n/k\rfloor-\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor^2.
$$
See Hurkyl's answer to [Simplifying $\sum_{i=1}^n{\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \rfloor}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897638/simplifying-sum-i-1n-lfloor-fracni-rfloor)

In other words, in a direct way,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor n/k \rfloor 
&= \sum_{j,k} [1 \leq j] [1 \leq k] [jk \leq n]\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{j\not=k} [1 \leq j] [1 \leq k] [jk \leq n]}_{\text{even}}+\sum_{j=k} [1 \leq j] [1 \leq k] [jk \leq n]\\
&\equiv \sum_{j=k} [1 \leq j] [1 \leq k] [jk \leq n] =\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor\pmod{2}\end{align}$$
where $[P]$ is $1$ if $P$ is true, and $0$ if false.

Comment: How do you get that?

Comment: This is my hint... ;-)

Comment: You knew this identity from the beginning?

Comment: @Md.ShamimAkhtar See my edit.

Comment: Can [k+1/1]+[k+1/2]+[k+1/3]+[k+1/4]+...+[k+1/k] be written as [k/1]+[k/2]+...+[k/k-1]+[k/k]+s(n), where s(n) denotes the number of positive divisors of k+1?

Comment: @Md.ShamimAkhtar I gave you a direct way.

Comment: Just asking if the relation is true

Comment: Yes, your relation is true where $s(n)$ are the number of proper divisors of $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to prove this by induction on $n$. When you replace $n$ by $n+1$, some terms in the expression will increase by $1$, count how many do for each $n$.